# udevadm test for net devices

Tags: files, udev, output

I am trying to dump the `udev` `env` to see my `%M`,`%m` and `%k` values (I am not happy with `udevadm info -a`)

For that in the `RUN` I write to a file under `tmp/` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818987/pass-attridvendor-as-argument-in-udev-script . But I don't see it created.

Moreover `udevadm test` won't invoke `RUN`. I tried `udevadm trigger` too and I didn't see the file getting created.

Do I keep rebooting my box? Any suggestions?

The filename is `020-persistent-net.rules` and placed under `etc/udev/rules.d` folder (initrd.gz archive) and the content is a rule like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", KERNELS=="0000:04:00.0", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="ethGi1"
```

`udevadm info -a` output is as below:

```
~$ sudo udevadm info -a /sys/class/net/ethGi1

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.3/0000:05:00.1/net/ethGi1':
    KERNEL=="ethGi1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="net"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{mtu}=="1500"
    ATTR{type}=="1"
    ATTR{netdev_group}=="0"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x1003"
    ATTR{speed}=="1000"
    ATTR{dormant}=="0"
    ATTR{addr_assign_type}=="0"
    ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0"
    ATTR{duplex}=="full"
    ATTR{iflink}=="4"
    ATTR{addr_len}=="6"
    ATTR{address}=="0c:c4:7a:34:20:21"
    ATTR{operstate}=="up"
    ATTR{broadcast}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    ATTR{tx_queue_len}=="1000"
    ATTR{ifalias}==""
    ATTR{ifindex}=="4"
    ATTR{link_mode}=="0"
    ATTR{carrier}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.3/0000:05:00.1':
    KERNELS=="0000:05:00.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="igb"
    ATTRS{irq}=="44"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x15d9"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{sriov_numvfs}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x020000"
    ATTRS{index}=="2"
    ATTRS{label}==" Intel Ethernet i350 #2"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{sriov_totalvfs}=="7"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000ffff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1521"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1521"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="0"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.3':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:03.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{irq}=="40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x15d9"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000ffff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2f0b"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0834"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="0"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,  without details it is difficult to  help you. Could you add more info: the udev rule file (its name, path, contents), the used script (its path, name, content, permissions). Which hardware you are targeting, is it the pci net interface as mentioned in your other question? Please add also the info collected from `udevadm info -a`.